# Openoffice3/jodconverter stopped working

Tags: java, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I have installed Openoffice.org3 on our server and it's running in headless
mode. We use it with jodconverter to convert word and excell files.

It used to work fine, but one day it just stopped working and I really
don't understand why.

When I run /usr/local/bin/java -jar 
jodconverter-2.2.2/lib/jodconverter-cli-2.2.2.jar

on an .xls file to convert it to a .csv file it just gives me:

Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed: could not save output document; OOo errorCode: 3088

If I run jodconverter on a word file, it just gives me an empty 
output file, or an other error code. That depends.

Our server have both openoffice 2.4 and 3.0 installed and neither
of the work now. (They both have the same problem) so it's not
directly a problem with the openoffice install.

I even tried to create a new user on the server, and run openoffice as him
but that don't work either.

So does anyone have any idear about what might be wrong, or how I
do get openoffice.org to produce some kind of log file/console outptu, 
so I can se whats going on.

I use
/opt/openoffice.org3/program/soffice.bin -headless -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;" &

Comment: What user is OpenOffice running as, what is the exact command you're executing, and what are the permissions on the output directory?

Comment: It is running as my user, the one I also use to do other development on the server. But as I said I also tried to run it with a newly created user. I even tried to run it as root(Just to test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up deleting both of my old openoffice installs and
installing a new version, and now it's working again. I still don't understand
why it stopped working but sometimes you just have to accept that a
reinstall is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, the soffice is running, but all conversion attempts fail.

My workaround is to run:

`Runtime.getRuntime("killtask /IM soffice.bin /F")`

To shutdown the OS process. And after this,

`Runtime.getRuntime("c:\\path\\start-openoffice-uno.bat")`.

For what it's worth I'm using OO 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

For me it started working after cleaning up all the files in /tmp related to OpenOffice